# Prevent <html>'s lang attribute from changing diacritics?

Tags: css, fonts, diacritics

I've recently encountered this problem: when I'm setting the `lang=` attribute for the `<html>` tag to `ro`, all the diacritics on the page are changed to the Cedilla-type characters.

Normal diacritics screenshot(șțȘȚ):

[image: Default diacritics] (pic1)

Cedilla-type characters(şţŞŢ)

[image: Cedilla-type diacritics] (pic2)

In the source, they are written as normal diacritics (pic1).

Now, the real problem is this:

Google Chrome:

- `<html>` -> text is like in pic2 - Cedilla-type diacritics
- `<html lang="ro">` -> again, text is like in pic2 - Cedilla-type diacritics
- `<html lang="en">` -> text is normal, like in pic1

Mozilla Firefox:

- `<html>` -> text is normal - pic1
- `<html lang="ro">` -> text is like in pic2 - Cedilla-type diacritics
- `<html lang="en">` -> text is normal, like in pic1

And two demos of the main cases:

```css
h2 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<html lang="ro">
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Diacritics: ș, ț, Ș, Ț</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
h2 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Diacritics: ș, ț, Ș, Ț</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

So, is there any way to keep the `lang="ro"` attribute, but have the normal diacritics(like in pic1)?

Thank you!

** Update, forgot to mention: Romanian diacritics are the normal ones - not the ones with cedilla.

Comment: In dev tools I see that Chrome adds `-webkit-locale: "ro"` to the html element; when I overwrite that with `"en"` explicitly, it displays as you want. I have no idea however what else this might affect; and I can’t find something comparable in Firefox on a quick glance.

Comment: @CBroe, Wow, didn't see that, thanks a lot. :D It seems to work in Chrome now if i remove lang at all and in CSS I add `-webkit-locale: "en"`. But would that affect the SEO in any way? I mean, the site will be in romanian, when Google will try to index it, won't he take that CSS property and say `This is in english!`?

Comment: I’d try and leave the `lang` attribute on the html element in place - especially in regard to search engines. Specifying `html { -webkit-locale: "en"; }` in your stylesheet somewhere should be enough to overwrite it. And I doubt that takes preference over the language specified in the HTML.

Comment: @CBroe that's great, thank you! :D

Comment: font-language-override for the standard (only FF as of writing). -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-language-override -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/77702242/2344083