# HTML lang attribute changes font completely

Tags: html, fonts, attributes, cyrillic, lang

tl;dr; - use the toggle button, see what happens:

```js
document.getElementById('toggle').addEventListener("click",function(){
if(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].lang == 'bg')
    document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].lang = 'en'
else
    document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].lang = 'bg'
});
```

```css
* {margin:0;padding:0;}
body {padding: 30px;
font-size:20px;
font-family: "Commissioner"}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html 
 lang="bg" dir="ltr">
<head>
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com"><link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Commissioner:wght@400;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
абвгд <br>
АБВГД <br>
abcde <br>
ABCDE <br>
<button id="toggle" onClick=>
toggle html attribute LANG="bg" to LANG="en"
</button>
</body>
```

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/zt6gapL5/)

When building a website, I naturally have a lang="xx" attribute on mu HTML tag. Took a while to delete each and every part of the document, to finally realize that it was causing my font to look totally different.

The website language is in `lang="bg"`(bulgerian), but the design I've been given, using that exact same font, must be with a lang="en" in order to look right.

On chrome, when I put
-webkit-locale: "en"
as CSS, it works. But only for chrome, obviously.

As you can see, the font is totally different:
lang="bg":

[image]

lang="en":

[image]

Option 1: using lang="en", when the site is NOT in EN
Option 2: removing the lang attribute whatsoever. Does the meta tag still work?
Option 3: Using CSS to fix things, however I couldn't find a solution for firefox...

-webkit-locale: 'en'; fixes the problem for webkit browsers. Sadly diversity is against me this time.

Comment: font-language-override for the standard (only FF as of writing). -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-language-override -- More on -webkit-locale at https://stackoverflow.com/a/77702242/2344083

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the difference in font appearance might be due to the 'Commissioner' font's feature settings. To resolve this issue, try adding `font-feature-settings: 'locl' 0;` to your CSS.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this will help get the right characterset. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KOI8-U     ....KOI8-U (RFC 2319) is an 8-bit character encoding, designed to cover Ukrainian,  It is based on KOI8-R, which covers Russian and Bulgarian

Comment: Thanks for answering. Unsure how to handle this though.   Adding "<meta charset="KOI8-U"/>" to the code didn't help, sadly. And using UTF-8 is preferable for me, always...

Comment: FYI - Unicode is UTF-8 ... Unicode is preferred to KOI-8 and its variants or other Cyrillic encodings in modern applications, especially on the Internet, making UTF-8 the dominant encoding for web pages.

Comment: This answer might help you a lot: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696499/meta-charset-utf-8-vs-meta-http-equiv-content-type

Comment: Encoding is not the issue. It's likely that the Commissioner font has different glyphs for Bulgarian, and that the language tagging is activating glyph substitutions.

Comment: Finally a valid comment. Thanks, Peter. 
Winston, I'm a dev for 10 years now, I know the general idea for building websites.......