# why does `lang` attribute effect how a character looks in html?

Tags: html, css, fonts

Why does the `lang` attribute effect rendering? For example, the following html renders like this on my computer

```html
<html>
<p lang="zh">lang=zh: 才 Aa</p>
<p lang="zh-tw">lang=zh-tw: 才 Aa</p>
<p lang="ja">lang=ja: 才 Aa</p>
</html>
```

[image: screenshot]

But if I explicitly specify a Chinese or Japanese only `font-family`, then they will look identical.

Does this mean my system/browser default font family contains multiple glyph for the same character, or does the browser select different font for each language?

Comment: there's a similar question but get downvoted and has no answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74730807/html-lang-attribute-changes-font-completely

Comment: "Why does the `lang` attribute effect rendering?" Because you're telling the browser the language of a particular element is different.

Comment: You can view what font the browser is using to render an element by right-clicking the element, selecting Inspect, then going to the Computed pane on the right-hand side. It should have a Rendered Fonts section at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Oh it's a browser feature. I found the related settings.

[image]